# Angularjs, what is the best way to capture when all XMLHttpRequest (XHR) have been resolved?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

With Angularjs,

I want to hide the ng-view until all XHR's have resolved. Because by default, the view will display while XHR's are still resolving.

This is a problem when the XHR(s) are not quick (example: .net IIS application warmup) and the screen is displayed to the user before the XHR's have resolved.

An example of the issue: I have a screen with select lists populated from a XHR and an anchor href string that gets built with data returned from a XHR. If the user attempts to use the select list, or click on the anchor, before the XHR's are resolved, they will get unexpected behavior. An empty select list. An anchor that doesn't work properly.

I'd rather not litter the view with ng-show or ng-disable and a bunch of flags and logic in the controller.

My thought was to hide the entire ng-view, until all XHR's are resolved, and then show the ng-view. This way I avoid littering the template with attributes, and I avoid complex hard to maintain logic in the controller.

I don't think angular offers a event I can capture with $on, so that wasn't a solution.

I came up with this, but I am not sure it's the best way to go about doing what I'm trying to do. What do you think?

**ng-view**

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">

    <div class="ng-cloak"
         ng-cloak
         ng-view
         ng-show="dataReady">
    </div>

</div>
```

**Parent Controller**

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("parentController",
    ["$scope"
    function ($scope) {

        $scope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function () {
            $scope.dataReady = false;
        });

        $scope.$on("loading:dataReady", function () {
            console.log("Data Ready");
            $scope.dataReady = true;
        });

    }
]);
```

**xhrService**

```
angular.module("myApp").service("xhrService", [
    "$q", function ($q) {
        var promises = [];

        return {
            push: function (promise) {
                promises.push(promise);
            },
            process: function () {
               return $q.all(promises).then(function () {
                   promises = [];
               });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

**Child Controller**

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myChildController",
    ["$scope", "$http", "xhrService",
    function ($scope, $http, xhrService) {

        $scope.myModel = {};

        var myXhrRequest = function () {
            return $http.get("api/myXhrRequest").then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.myModel.myProperty = response.data;
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                });
        };


        xhrService.push(myXhrRequest());

        xhrService.process().then(function () {
            $scope.$emit("loading:dataReady");
        });

    }
    ]);
```

Comment: how many requests are you calling at the start of your app?

Comment: @jorg I don't understand the point to that question

Comment: wondering if it would be worth it combining them into one, if you only need them at the start of the app.